# how json data into pug template (mongoose)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, coffeescript, pug

I'm trying to develop a website using angular mongo and node (coffee script and mongoose). I got some database value from the mongo db but I need to show the data into the pug template engine

here is the code

```
    init: =>
  @Sign
    .find()
    .then (result) =>

      @scope.sign = result.data
    .catch (err) =>
      console.log err
```

@scope.sign is the Json Object .. 
I need to show one column elements('names of the product") from the Json object to the pug .. somebody please help me

Comment: what format is the JSON? can you show an example of the JSON?

Comment: { _id: 59f2fcbca65e3f39a309473f,
    createdAt: 2017-10-27T09:30:36.357Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-10-27T09:34:48.828Z,
    name: 'machan peru madhure',
    __v: 0,
    priceunit: 'USD',
    price: '20000',
    holdtime: '90',
    slot: '9',
    address: 'location or address',
    resolution: '920px',
    width: '100',
    height: '100' }

Comment: use:
each product in result.data
>>>>p= product.name

Answer (score 0):

Use [iteration](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) to loop through the data.

```
each product in result.data
    div(class="product-item")
        p= product.name
```

Comment: is that `@scope.sign= result.data` is correct..???
the `result.data` is returning a json